# OpenGL copy/paste out part of a texture into another texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures

I need to take a bunch of images from different sprite sheets and put them in a particular way into one texture for my game (although I"m not very familiar with openGL). So, what is the best way to make a texture from a smaller portion of a texture in OpenGL, and what is the best way to combine two or more textures into one texture in OpenGL?

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way to do this using `glBlitFramebuffer()`. You will need two FBOs (framebuffer objects): one for the source, and one for the destination. Then you attach the source and destination textures to the FBOs, and call `glBlitFramebuffer()`.

The code could look like this, with `srcTexId` the texture name of your source texture, and `dstTexId` the destination:

```
GLuint fboIds[2];
glGenFramebuffers(2, fboIds);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[0]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, srcTexId, 0);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[1]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                       GL_TEXTURE_2D, dstTexId, 0);

glBlitFramebuffer(srcX0, srcY0, srcX1, srcY1,
                  dstX0, dstY0, dstX1, dstY1,
                  GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

The first 8 arguments to `glBlitFramebuffer()` specify the rectangles in the source and destination textures.

Comment: There's a copy&paste error at the `DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` binding: should be `fboIds[1]`.

Comment: What are the imports? Eclipse doesn't automatically import lwjgl things for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways this can be achieved in OpenGL. Assuming a reasobably modern GL version, I would recommend using [FBOs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object). Bind the destination texture as the color attachment for one FBO. Then, you can simply render textured quads (using the source texture regions) to it. You could even skip the render step completely, and also use a FBO for the source textures, and directly blit the parts using [`glBlitFramebuffer()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FBO api. Could you please show me an example?

Comment: Maybe [these examples](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples) might be of some help.